# How to restart WiFi adapter?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

when my laptop awake after sleep the WiFi adapter shows cross,and in order to again connect to WiFi i restart my laptop.Is there any thing i would do to get rid-off this thing **OR** is there any way i can restart my WiFi adapter through CMD.

I tried to update WiFi adapter drivers but no luck.

My WiFi Adapter is **Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter**

Answer (score 1):

Most Laptos on FN Keys, they have a Combination (FN + F1...) and so on  that disables the Wireless and with the same Combination it re-enables it again.